# Append a list on to another in oCaml

Tags: list, recursion, ocaml, tail-recursion

I need a tail recursive function that appends a list1 infront of list2.

I tried it this way

```
let rec append lst1 lst2 acc = 
  match lst1 with 
  | [] -> acc @ lst2
  | hd::tl -> append lst1 tl (hd::acc);;

append [1;3;4] [3;4;2] [];;
```

But the result is "time out" every time

Answer (score 0):

You have unbounded recursion because you're not updating `lst1` when you evaluate your test case:

```
append [1;3;4] [3;4;2] []
append [1;3;4] [3;4] (1 :: [])
append [1;3;4] [3;4] (1 :: 1 :: [])
```

This will run forever, which explains your "time out" issue.

You need to update `lst1`. E.g.

```
let rec append lst1 lst2 acc = 
  match lst1 with 
  | [] -> acc @ lst2
  | hd::tl -> append tl lst2 (hd::acc)
```

```
append [1;3;4] [3;4;2] []
append [3;4] [3;4;2] (1 :: [])
append [4] [3;4;2] (3 :: 1 :: [])
append [] [3;4;2] (4 :: 3 :: 1 :: [])
[4;3;1] @ [3;4;2]
[4;3;1;3;4;2]
```

But that's not right. You need to think about your logic. Lists in OCaml are singly-linked lists. `[1; 3; 4]` is equivalent to `1 :: 3 :: 4 :: []` and `[1; 3; 4; 3; 4; 2]` is `1 :: 3 :: 4 :: 3 :: 4 :: 2 :: []`.

You just need to replace `[]` in the first list with `[3; 4; 2]`. The basic form for this is going to look like:

```
let rec append lst1 lst2 =
  match lst1 with
  | [] -> ...
  | hd::tl -> hd :: append ... ...
```

Comment: let rec append lst1 lst2 =      
    match lst1 with
      | [] -> ...
      | hd::tl -> hd :: append ... ...


This doesn't seem to be tail recursive

Comment: You're right. It isn't. You either need to figure out how to use an accumulator or: `let[@tail_mod_cons] rec append ...`